# Dynamic Where Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I've been doing research on how to dynamically make queries for linq.  I'm creating a UI for a web application which allows them to select properties from a DB and set where clauses to build reports dynamically.  All of the questions I've seen on stack or other sites reference using Dynamic Linq and LinqKit to Solve the problem, example [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d37dbeb5-82d4-4f67-8715-cc314486e836/a-straight-forward-way-to-construct-a-dynamic-querydynamic-where-clause-in-lightswitch?forum=lightswitch) .  However I can't find an solution to express the syntax.

```
// This attempts to grab out a title whose from the Database whose
// Copyright Date equals 2006
propName = "CopyrightDate";
Model.Titles.Where(t => t.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(t, null) == "2006");
```

I want to do something like this but in Linq to Entities.  Linq to entities doesn't support reflection like that, I do not want to pull out all of the data and run Linq to Object the DB is too Large.  Any Suggestions on how to write this in Dynamic Linq.    Bonus points if you can cast the type to the property type so It can be evaultuated with standard operators (== , > , < , etc..).

Comment: You've already linked to questions that show ways of solving this exact problem, and of course there are plenty of others out there that can be found with some basic research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can rewrite your query using [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library):

```
var propName = "CopyrightDate";
var propValue = "2006";
Model.Titles.Where(string.Format("{0}=@0", propName), propValue);
```

`string.Format("{0}=@0", propName)` produces the query string for the `Where` clause, which would be `"CopyrightDate=@0"` in this case. `@0` specifies the parameter for the query, which becomes `propValue`.

Comment: this seems to generate the correct sql, I need to pull out the TitleName from the Select which I can by 

Model.Titles.Where(string.Format("{0}=@0", propName), propValue).Select("TitleName") but From here I can't do FirstOrDefault() and the >ToList() extension isn't there.  Any Idea on how to do this

Comment: @johnny5 Once you do `FirstOrDefault` you can't do `ToList` because it's a single item. `Select(string)` in the [source](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DynamicLinq/System.Linq.Dynamic/Dynamic.cs) returns an untyped `IQueryable` (i.e. not `IQueryable<T>`) so you need to follow it by a cast to the specific type of the field that you are creating, i.e. `Select("TitleName").Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault()` and so on.

Comment: I just mean both extensions weren't accessible, I know you can't chain them :).  I switched the example to something more simple which just uses an ID.  I'm trying the case however I keep getting an exception "System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(system.linq.iqueryable) is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context"

         var id = Model.Titles.Where(string.Format("{0}=@0", propName),         propValue).Select("ID").AsQueryable().Cast<int>.FirstOrDefault();

I also tried this code with out  the .AsQueryAble() //(sorry Idk how to format these Comments)

Comment: @johnny5 You forgot parentheses after the `Cast<int>`: it should be `Cast<int>()`.

Comment: Thanks, This should most of the problems, I'm going to mark this as solved for now,  I'm sure I can figure out a way to use reflection to cast the type automatically.  You've saved me your the best!

Comment: can you help me figure out the cast for an anonymous type attached is the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367241/dynamically-linq-select-cast-to-ienumerable/26367369#26367369

Answer (score 3):

What the LINQ-to-entities `Where` extension method wants, is an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. You can create such an expression like this:

```
// Create lambda expression: t => t.CopyrightDate == "2006"
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
     Expression.Equal(
         Expression.Property(parameter, "CopyrightDate"),
         Expression.Constant("2006")
     ),
     parameter
);
```

where `T` is the type of your class containing the `CopyrightDate` property.

```
var result = context.Titles
    .Where(lambda)
    .ToList();
```

---

A somewhat more general solution is:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> Comparison<T>(ExpressionType comparisonType,
                                        string propertyName, object compareTo)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(compareTo);
    Expression body = Expression.MakeBinary(comparisonType, property, constant);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: I switched this to a greaterthan but the problem is the operation doesn't work on nullable types

    'DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2006);

            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Title), "t");
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Title, bool>>(
                 Expression.GreaterThan(
                     Expression.Property(parameter, "CopyrightDate"),
                     Expression.Constant(testDate)
                 ),
                 parameter
            );
'

Comment: Of what type is your table column? You cannot compare `column = 2006` if it is a datetime column! You would have to compare (in SQL) `YEAR(column) = 2006`. Or, if it is a number column `column=2006` or if it is a text column `column='2006'`. I'd suggest you to first create a working non-dynamic query, before trying to create a complicated expression tree.